# Selenium grid ubuntu host can't create node in Windows guest

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, ubuntu, selenium

I want to create a Selenium grid hosted in my ubuntu linux 12.04.
My goal is to make this selenium grid communication with a Windows VM with a node role.
My problem is that when i create the selenium grid in the Windows VM i have this error

> 14:35:00.200 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://xxxxx:4444/grid/register
>   16:35:01.232 INFO - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Connect to xxxxx:4444 [IP] failed: Connection refused: connect

My VM is a Windows XP. I try to disable the Firewall.
I'm sure that is a Ubuntu problem, because with an other Windows VM, the problem is the same. I can ping Host to Guest and Guest to Host
In ubuntu, i disable the firewall too, but nothing change.

In ubuntu i declare the hub like this

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role hub
```

In the Windows VM i declare the node like this

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role node
```

Any ideas about what is blocking the communication ? Thanks for help _

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure during the virtualization process, the ports 4444 for the grid and 5555 for the nodes are being opened.

Then in your node role, make sure to specify the `-hub` parameter.  when not specifying the hub parameter, it defaults to `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I opened the 4444 and 5555 ports and add the hub info and when i replace localhost by the good ip, it works ! Thanks a lot :)